# How to map structures inheriting a protocol?

Tags: swift

First of all I am really sorry about the terrible wording of the question but I am not sure how to put it.

Imagine we have a structure such as Fruit.

```
    struct Fruit {
        enum FruitType {
            case apple
            case pear
            case unknown
        }
    
        let id: String
        let type: FruitType
        let apple: Apple?
        let pear: Pear?
    }

    struct Apple {
        let something: String 
    }

    struct Pear {
        let somethingElse: String
    }
```

I'd like to have the structures AppleFruit and PearFruit which would follow the protocol FruitProtocol and have the id of the fruit and the data of either Apple or Pear depending on the type. I have tried something like this but it does not work.

```
    init?(from fruit: Fruit) {
        switch fruit.type {
        case .apple:
            guard let apple = fruit.apple else { return nil }

            Apple(...)
        case .pear:
            guard let pear = coreAsset.pear else { return nil }
            
            Pear(...)
        default:
            self = nil
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? I have tried with `return` or `self =` but none of them work.

Comment: You mention a “FruitProtocol”, but there’s no protocols here at all. Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

In your description, Fruit isn't a protocol, it's [an enum with associated data](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148):

```
enum Fruit {
    case apple(Apple)
    case pear(Pear)
}
```

This will handle everything you're describing.

If there really is just one property in both (or a very small number of properties), then you can embed that directly into the enum:

```
enum Fruit {
    case apple(something: String)
    case pear(somethingElse: String)
}
```

This can get unwieldy very quickly, so it can often be better to have a separate struct to hold all the properties.

Comment: Interestingly, what OP stumbled into was pretty much how protocols with associated types work (absent the C-style union for an OR type). Multiple values, only 1 of which is valid, and a descriminator which selects between them